# Yoga server deployment to the now.sh shows directory listing instedad the application

Tags: node.js, vercel

I can run the app locally without any issue by `yarn start` command. here I have provided photographs which represent my problem. I googled and noticed several people faces the same problem. but their context is different.

[image]

Comment: Could you post your `now.json` as a code block please?

Comment: {
  "version": 2
}

   //  this is the code inside my now.json

Comment: Do you have a `build` step? How are you compiling your babel source to js?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Now publishes your files as a static directory. You can add a builder to your `now.json` file to tell Now how to build and deploy your site.

In a case where `app.js` contains a web server application, your `now.json` might look like this:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "my-project",
  "builds": [
    {"src": "app.js", "use": "@now/node"}  
  ]
}
```

This tells Now to use the `@now/node` builder to generate a lambda that runs `app.js` to respond to requests.

If your app is purely js+html to be run on the client machine, you wouldn't need the lambda, but you can still build the source before deploying it as static files with `@now/static-build`.

Check out the Now docs for more info: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/basics/#introducing-a-build-step

Comment: I tried it this way as well. it is still the directory structure. but the problem is I am using es6 syntax in my application and use babel (@babel/preset-env)  so my start command is babel-node src/app.js is that the problem?